# How to make log-rotate change take effect

Tags: linux, syslog, logrotate

I followed [this link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-logfiles-locating.html) to change log-rotate configuration for RHEL 6

After I made the change to config file, what should I do to let this take effect?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

`logrotate` uses `crontab` to work. It's scheduled work, not a daemon, so no need to reload its configuration.
When the `crontab` executes `logrotate`, it will use your new config file automatically.
If you need to test your config you can also execute `logrotate` on your own  with the command:

```
logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/your-logrotate-config
```

If you want to have a debug output use argument  -d

```
logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/your-logrotate-config
```

You may need to be root or a specific user to run this command.
<strike>Or as mentioned in comments, identify the `logrotate` line in the output of the command `crontab -l` and execute the command line</strike> refer to [slm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116141/53092) to have a precise cron.daily explanation

Comment: Just to add to your answer, the cron entry for `logrotate` is scheduled to run once a day.

Comment: @Ketan, so, how can i make it affect right away? thanks

Comment: Not sure. One possibility is to find the corresponding entry from crontab via `crontab -l` and execute it.

Comment: If you want it to take effect immediately run the cron afterwords.

Comment: You can also just run `logrotate` directly as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: `/you/config/file` can be misunderstood as a path to a particular config for some application's logs, such as `/etc/logrotate.d/foo`. This is usually wrong; only the main config should be used because others can inherit some values from the main one.

Comment: `logrotate` has a `-d` option for testing (or "debugging"), I'd recommend running it at least once with that.

Comment: A very common frustration is the new, required su directive `su root syslog`. Which brings logrotate to a halt when not added in. To top off people's frustration, when they add the directive, and then run (force) logrotate, it continues to spit out "`error: skipping "/var/log/syslog" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which  is not "root" ...`" for 20 hrs after the config change, as if the the settings/process are cached!? If you are stuck there, chgrp on /var/log to root, run logrotate, chgrp back to syslog. It will clear up by next run

Answer (score 55):

Most of the `logrotate` setups I've seen on various distros runs out of the `/etc/cron.daily`. There's a shell script there aptly named `logrotate`.

#### Example

```
$ ls -l /etc/cron.daily/logrotate 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 180 May 18  2011 /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

#### Manual run

If you want to make it run manually simply run the script as root:

```
$ sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

If you take a look at a script that's typically there, it shows you how you can also run `logrotate` manually, by simply running `logrotate` + the path to its configuration file.

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 50):

It should be automatic via cron.  You can force it to test your changes.

For global logrotate:

```
sudo logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

For a single conf file:

```
sudo logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.d/someapp.conf
```

Comment: `-f` for force rotation, there is also `-d` for debug, which is also Dry run, it will print everything it would have done but not actually do it.

Answer (score 7):

On my CentOS 6.5 machine for setting up logrotatefor nginx I had to do this:

```
logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
```

And then I checked if logrotate taking care of my new nginx config like this:

```
cat /var/lib/logrotate.status
```

Edit : cat /var/lib/logrotate/status